# Putting newsletter sign up on homepage in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, model-view-controller

I want to allow people to sign up for a newsletter on the homepage of a website. I am not trying to make a user resource or anything like that. I want to have a form on the front page that will simply save their email to a database and use that to send mail in the future.

I was wondering what the best way to implement this was. I was thinking of making an Email model and setting the home page as the Email new path. I also plan on having a static pages controller for simple about and contact stuff. Is it possible to call the new Email method from the static pages controller so that way I won't have to create an EmailController as well? Could I do something like include a home method in my StaticPagesController and put the form for new EmailModel in the home view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call this model NewsletterSubscription.  It's a little lettery but it describes the intent.  Here is the backbone of this

```
NewsletterSubscription
  email: string
  active: boolean, default: true
  message: text

  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, with: some_format_you_want

NewsletterSubscriptionsController
  def new
    @newsletter_subscriber = NewsletterSubscriber.new
  end
  def create
    #create your subscription based on params and redirect acordingly
  end
end
```

Then in your views you will have a _form that you will render somewhere on your homepage that will display the form.

Comment: Ok that's kind of what I was thinking. Can I put that form in a view from another controller like a StaticPagesContorller or would it have to go in the view for NewsletterSubscriptionsController new method?

Comment: Hey just saw the update, yes, you can render the form view anywhere in the web app.  Rails takes care of  generating the proper form html to route the request to the proper controller.

Comment: Hey so did this answer what you needed?

Comment: Oh yes thank you! I'm going to implement this tomorrow. I will let you know the results.

Comment: yeah I tried to but I don't have enough reputation to give you one, I would if I could!

Comment: ok I've been running to some issues. I'm trying to put the form_for(@newsletter_subscription) on my StaticPages home.html.erb view but I get an error saying that the argument can't be nil. Now I'm sure it's because of the instance variable but I have no clue how to get it to work using the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right about the new problem you are experiencing which I saw you posted on the Answer Comment. i.e. your `form_for(@newsletter_subscription)` throwing `argument can't be nil`

You can define it directly in your StaticPage `home.html.erb` such that you have:

```
<%= form_for NewsletterSubscriber.new do |f| %>
    #Put your form definitions here e.g.
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %> #Defining `f.email_field` here is not a problem, HTML5 surely will digest that..
    <% f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But know that defining it directly as I did in the code first line `<%= form_for NewsletterSubscriber.new do |f| %>`violates Rails Paradigm.